# How to remove [''] in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that has a column ID and Name. For example:

```
ID| Name   
1 | ['John Mark']
```

What I want to happen is to remove the [''] from the name. I tried using `str.strip` but it only removes the brackets.

I'm only a beginner so sorry.

Comment: if the `Name` col has only 1 value in the list, you can use `df['Name']=df['Name'].str[0]`

Comment: The Name became [

Comment: okay, this means it is not a valid list? its just a string representation of a list, can you try `df['Name'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0]` make sure you import the ast module first by `import ast`

Comment: There is still ['']

Comment: sure, I will open the question if you can please create a code to reconstruct the dataframe my be `df.head().to_dict()` would help

Comment: @anky_91 posted a solution that works for the _one example_ you have in your question. For us to help, we may need some more examples, or a small line of code that can generate the dataframe for us

Comment: aa = df.loc[df['Id'] == Id]['Name'].values
tt = str(Id)+"-"+aa

Comment: it's for a face recognition when matching the face to  the database

Answer (score 3):

Pandas series supports string operations. For example;

```
data_set['Name'] = data_set['Name'].str.replace("['", "")
data_set['Name'] = data_set['Name'].str.replace("']", "")
```

Is it best practice? Not sure. But should work.

Comment: Does it throw error or didn't give expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [[1,"['John Mark']"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["ID","Name"])
```

```
    ID           Name
0   1   ['John Mark']
```

Replace can accept a regex pattern.

```
>>> df["Name"].str.replace("^\['|'\]$","")
0    John Mark
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

In case it's not a single quote:

```
>>> df["Name"].str.replace("^\[.|.\]$","")
0    John Mark
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Tried df["Name"].str.replace(^\['|'\]$",""), didnt work.

Comment: use the first example I provided to generate the data/dataframe that doesn't work and update your question; as @wundermahn hinted at / mentioned in the comment.   i took best guess jab at regenerating your data so it doesn't work is within expectations.

Comment: ah.  based on what you've responded, the next best guess of your data is that what you think is a single quote is not an actual single quote.   it line up with the strip issue, which i would have constructed as str.strip("[']").   would also explain the left bracket in str[0].  also the mismatch in eval.   try using a "." instead of a quote in the replace statement to match any character next to the bracket..